# Ambiguous Conversion Syntax in Go

Tags: go, type-conversion

I have the following type definition:

```
type reader io.Reader
```

and I want this `reader` type to implement the `io.Reader` interface, so I do:

```
func (r reader) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    return io.Reader(r).Read(p)
}
```

The problem is this: `io.Reader(r)` could mean one of two things:

- Convert `r` to its underlying type (`io.Reader`)
- Assert statically (checked by compiler) that `r` satisfies the `io.Reader` interface (since we've defined a `Read([]byte) (int, error)` method, it does). Create a new `io.Reader` interface value and store `r` inside it.

I want the former to happen. If the latter happens, when I call `io.Reader(r).Read(p)`, it will call `r`'s underlying `Read` method (which we are inside at the moment), and it will infinite loop. What I would *like* to happen is to extract the underlying `io.Reader` *inside* `r`, and use *its* `Read` method.

Of course, I could just test to see in practice which of the two of these happens, but I'm curious in general about how these problems are resolved by the Go compiler. I couldn't find the relevant information in the language spec.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? (this isn't valid Go) Your `reader` type is an interface, and you can't have an interface receiver for a method.

Comment: Neither happens. You cannot convert interface types to their underlying types. You have to use a type assertion like r.(io.Reader).Read() which panics if it fails. The compile cannot do static checks here.

Answer (score 9):

You can't use an interface type `reader` which is defined as `io.Reader` as a receiver type in `func (r reader) {}`.

You need to define the reader type as a specific type

```
type reader struct {
    // stuff
}
```

To answer your question, the `io.Reader(r)` means assert at compile time that `r` satisfies the `io.Reader` interface and create a new `io.Reader` interface value and store `r` inside it. (your second choice).

So if you try the above you'll get an infinite recursion.

The idea of an underlying `io.Reader` makes no sense in Go since you can't define methods on interfaces, only on concrete types.

You can of course embed types within each other which might look like this

```
type reader struct {
    other io.Reader
}
```

Which you would then call

```
func (r reader) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    return r.other.Read(p)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the receiver method is only for Struct, Furthermore you are trying to implement one interface to another interface. I dont know if this is posible in go. In other languages like Java that implementation is solved with abstract class but GoLang do not have this topics in your core.